# Sharepoint - One feature that creates more than one content type?

Tags: sharepoint, content-type

Is it possible to create more than just 1 content type with just one feature in Sharepoint?

I've a got a project where a couple of content types inherits from another one and I have 5 features just creating those content types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In fact sharepoint has a feature that has basic content types defined in `[12 Hive]/TEMPLATES/FEATURES/ctypes` folder.

Just define multiple `<ContentType>` tags as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593292/deploy-3-contenttypes-using-1-feature-only-2-gets-deployed) and it works!

Comment: Thank you! It'll be easier to install and maintain!

Comment: By the way, there is a trick to activate multiple features by only activating one. For a feature, you can set Hidden='TRUE' so it does not appear in feature list. However on other feature you can define ActivationDependency that will activate dependant features. However it does not work recursively.